# Spring security returns String as principal instead of UserDetails on controller

Tags: java, spring-security

The question is: I have an Auth server(spring security) and a Resource server，The Resource server can't get principal user correctly.

Spring Boot Version: 2.0.7
Spring Cloud Version: Finchley.SR2

Firstly, I go to get access token from Auth-server, and It is the success.
Then, I use the token to post the Resource-server, and the controller of Resource-server can get a principal.
However, the principal is a string, not a UserDetails Object.

Auth Server websecurity config like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private MaliUserDetailsService maliUserDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.userDetailsService(maliUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

Auth Server UserDetailsService：

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Resouce Server Controller：

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(Authentication authentication) {
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

    return "hello " + userDetails.getUsername();
}
```

When I post to resource server, it cast a exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

[image]

===============
Then I tried to change to controller code like this:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String test(Authentication authentication) {
    return "hello " + authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
}
```

The result is "hello admin".  (admin is my username)
[image]

Why the principal in the controller is a string instead of UserDetails Object? How to solve it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186048/discussion-on-question-by-defit-spring-security-returns-string-as-principal-inst).

Comment: I was having a similar issue and the chat thread pointed out my problem, which was fairly obvious in the end.  I had a custom filter that did authentication using auth tokens.  When setting the principal property of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken I was using the username instead of a UserDetails object.